# AngularJS directive with repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

Is it possible to have a directive with a repeater inside it?

What I want is to create a list of people in alphabetical order where the people list is filtered for each group of letters.

The directive is as follows:

```
.directive('azList', ['$compile', function($compile){

    var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#'.split('');
    var group = '';
    letters.forEach(function(letter){
        group = group + '\
        <div class="list__group" id="list_' + letter + '">\
            <h4 class="list__header">' + letter + '</h4>\
            <ul class="list__items">\
                <li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy: [{{person.lastname}}, {{person.firstname}}] | firstLetter:{{person.lastname}}:' + letter + '">\
                    <a ui-sref="people.details({ personId: {{person.id}} })">\
                        <span class="list__icon"><img src="img/avatar.png"></span>\
                        <span class="list__text">\
                            <span class="list__text__name">{{person.firstname}} <b>{{person.lastname}}</b></span>\
                        </span>\
                    </a>\
                </li>\
            </ul>\
        </div>';
    });

    return {
        restrict: 'AECM',
        template: group
    };

}])
```

And then the filter:

```
.filter('firstLetter', function () {
    return function (input, key, letter) {
        input = input || [];
        var out = [];
        input.forEach(function (item) {
            if(letter == '#') {
                if ( !isNaN(parseInt(item[key][0])) )
                    out.push(item);
            }
            else if (item[key][0].toLowerCase() == letter.toLowerCase()) {
                out.push(item);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
});
```

And then I use it like:

```
<az-list></az-list>
```

However I just get the list of letters and it doesn't call the repeaters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive should have return object which will be Directive Definition object. I'm not sure what you are doing there in your directive.

```
.directive('azList', ['$compile', function($compile){
  return {
     restrict: 'AECM',
     template: '<div>myTempolate</div>'
  }
})];
```

Additionally you did have used `{{}}` in few places while applying filter over `ng-repeat`, you should change that to below.

```
    <div class="list__group" id="list_' + letter + '">\
        <h4 class="list__header">' + letter + '</h4>\
        <ul class="list__items">\
            <li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy: [person.lastname, person.firstname] | firstLetter:person.lastname:' + letter + '">\
                <a ui-sref="people.details({ personId: person.id })">\
                    <span class="list__icon"><img src="img/avatar.png"></span>\
                    <span class="list__text">\
                        <span class="list__text__name">{{person.firstname}} <b>{{person.lastname}}</b></span>\
                    </span>\
                </a>\
            </li>\
        </ul>\
    </div>';
```

See demo [**plunkr here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QngY7khBSaOdYzdf47jM?p=preview)

---

Ideally you should use `ng-repeat` over the template to repeat that template several times. Having directive just to generate a template wouldn't make sense as `ng-repeat` is already there for that.

**`ng-repeat` Version**

```
<div ng-repeat="letter in letters" class="list__group" id="list_{{letter}}">
    <h4 class="list__header">{{letter}}</h4>
    <ul class="list__items">
        <li ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy: [person.lastname, person.firstname] | firstLetter:person.lastname:letter">
            <a ui-sref="people.details({ personId: person.id })">
                <span class="list__icon"><img src="img/avatar.png"></span>
                <span class="list__text">
                  <span class="list__text__name">
                    {{person.firstname}} 
                   <b>{{person.lastname}}</b></span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah tried (see amend) and I get the list now, but the repeaters inside the directive don't get fired. Basically I want to repeat within a repeater.

Comment: Or are you suggesting I nest a repeater inside a repeater? Which might work just as well!

Comment: @Cameron yes I'd just have a simple ng-repeat instead of having another directive to wrap it.. which ideally doesn't make sense..

Comment: Hi, I can't get the letter to pass from the first repeater. See the code here: http://pastebin.com/t2RyaMxA If I replace `'letter` with just `A` it works fine, so the repeater logic is fine, just doesn't like the letter being passed... Gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: May I know which suggested option you are trying?

Comment: I'm using your second block of code example, but I have a repeater wrapped around it to show the list of letters (this works fine) but the letter isn't getting passed to the firstLetter filter.

Comment: Do look at updated answer, I did missed to add ng-repeat on template :D

Comment: Yeah using that, but because we're passing `person.lastname` instead of `lastname` it breaks my filter as we're passing a resource instead of just the value of lastname... The filter is shown in my original post.

Comment: Could you create/ update my plunkr, so that I could dig into it.

Comment: Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/r3PLOTEkZbSUpaIRrNxo?p=preview as you can see the letters are coming out fine. It looks like the key isn't being passed. As if I hardcode it to be 'lastname' within the filter itself then it works.

Comment: Will look at it..once I've access to machine.

Comment: @Cameron by having `person.lastname` it working, look at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mgHHs26qB43LDZ9jHJW0?p=preview)

Comment: In the console the key is undefined and the out is an empty array, so nothing is ever matched using the filter so all you see is the letters and none of the people are listed in that plunker.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return just a string (group in your example) in the directive part. You have to return a directive definition object. You can read more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code don't have any `people`. So it does not go into `ng-repeat` loop.